# Migrate FieldCollection with host entity FieldCollection

Tags: migrations, entities

in our Drupal application, we have a few field collections that themselves have field collections. It looks like this:

```
field_collection1
 ├── field_xyz
 ├── field_collection2
 └── field_collection3
```

I am currently implementing migrations for all our content, and am a little bit stuck trying to figure out the best way to migrate these collections. I have absolutely no problem migrating `field_collection1` and `field_xyz` using the `MigrateDestinationFieldCollection` class, but don't know how to approach the two nested collections.

Looking at the documentation available for [migrating field collections](https://www.drupal.org/node/1900640), the only two `host_entity_types` that are supported seem to be `node` and `term`. `field_collection1` is of course neither a node nor a term, so I am not sure how I would set it as the host entity. Is that even possible?

If not, would it be a sensible option to create the two nested migrations in the `complete` hook if the `field_collection1` migration?

I am really appreciating any feedback on this.